# How can I generate XML?

Tags: xml, google-apps-script

I need to generate a XML document, using specific data from a spreadsheet.

I'm using GoogleScript, but I don't see any libraries to help me generate XML. (The standard XML Service only parses XML)

Am I forced to do this by-hand or am I missing something?

Can you recommend any libraries or Javascript functions that might assist in generating XML?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can build XML documents using HtmlService templates. You *can* also create documents with the Xml service by starting with an empty document (Xml.parse('') or something similar) and then manipulating it with Xml.element() and the like, but I'd suspect that the first idea is much easier.

Answer (score 4):

Recently I found an ability to generate XML using a `XML` class (not `Xml`) which exists in GAS. An example is following

```
function makeXML() {
  var xml = new XML('<a/>');
  xml['@attrib1'] = 'atribValue';
  xml.data = 'dataValue';
  xml.data.sub_data = 'subDataValue';
  return xml.toString();
}

function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.add(app.createLabel(makeXML()));
  return app;
}
```

The output for this script is `<a attrib1="atribValue"> <data> dataValue <sub_data>subDataValue</sub_data> </data> </a>`

Answer (score 0):

paste it in a excel like and then export.

Otherwise use C-Xerces from Apache

Answer (score 0):

[According to Google](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml/#parseJS%28Object%29) the proper way to do this is to use parseJS to transform a nested set of javascript arrays into the XML.

> To create an XmlDocument instance that can be serialized to a string
>   representation via XmlDocument.toXmlString(), use the method
>   parseJS(jsObject), which builds an XML document from a nested set of
>   JavaScript arrays.

The link on that page is bad, but [you can find the documentation for parseJS here.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml/xml?hl=en#parseJS%28Object%29)

I don't love this approach but I find the creation side of the documentation on their XML module to be poor, so this is the one I went with. In my case I needed to map each row into an element where some pieces were sub-elements and some were attributes. This could be written more briefly but I'm not sure it would be more understandable. At least not to me.

So this is the solution I came up with for my needs, which creates the top enclosing XML and then adds node by node. Once its done it opens a matching google document and puts the rendered XML into it. There's some very basic checking to make sure I have the minimum needed cells so if one of my users puts in a bad row I just skip it. It also allows me to not screw around with worrying about extra blank lines at the bottom, etc.

```
  var now = new Date();
  var UTCString = '';
  UTCString = UTCString.concat(now.getFullYear(),'-',now.getMonth()+1,'-',now.getDate(),'T',now.getHours(),':',now.getMinutes(),':',now.getSeconds(),'+00:00');  

  var fullDoc = ["entities", {"type":"federal-body"}, {"updated":UTCString}];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  // This selects ALL the data w/o having to specify a range
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();

  // This logs the spreadsheet in CSV format with a trailing comma
  for (var i in values) {
    //not elegant but worth it for the get-all-range
    if (i==0)
      continue;
    if (values[i][0] && values[i][2]) {
      //make an object if column 1 is empty
      //column 0 is the id attribute
      //column 1, if present, is the parent-id attribute
      if (values[i][1]) {
        var node = ["entity", {"id": values[i][0]}, {"parent-id": values[i][1]} ];       
      } else {
        var node = ["entity", {"id": values[i][0]} ];
      }
      //column 2 is the name value and has the attribute of role:official
      node.push([ "name", {"role" : "official"}, values[i][2] ]);
      //column 3, if present, is the abbr value
      if (values[i][3]) {
        node.push([ "abbr", values[i][3] ]);
      }
      //column 4, if present, is a name value with role:historical
      if (values[i][4]) {
        node.push([ "name", {"role" : "historical"}, values[i][3] ]);
      }
      //column 5, if present, is a name value with role:leadership
      if (values[i][5]) {
        node.push([ "name", {"role" : "leadership"}, values[i][5]]);
      }     
      fullDoc.push(node);   
   } 
  }

  var xml = Xml.parseJS(fullDoc);

  //put it in the file
  var doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/document/d/17WNYtvjCgR-w3m3tIFNmHlr3aVLqfUaobGqFu-hIGks/edit');
  var header = doc.getHeader();
  if (header)
    header.clear();
  var footer = doc.getFooter();
  if (footer)
    footer.clear();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  body.setText(xml.toXmlString());
```

I've put this into a menu item at the moment which requires manually running but eventually I'll look into firing it on save. The output XML is unformatted but since I'm just shoving it into a database (an update process I intend to later automate) I don't care.

It would be smarter of me to use the column headers for the attributes but I didn't want to mess with the source doc from the client.

You can see [the source spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Asq4MpW95tWqdHA2b0k4N1NMVGt5MVZDalBUSzB3RkE&usp=sharing) as well as [the output](https://docs.google.com/document/d/17WNYtvjCgR-w3m3tIFNmHlr3aVLqfUaobGqFu-hIGks/edit?usp=sharing) for comparison.